# jQuery.load 404 error

Tags: jquery, html

I have two plain html files.
The first has a tree on the left from which you select a category and then it displays on the right the html file according to the selection.
the folder structure is /main/Pages, the main folder contains the main html and the Pages folder the child htmls.

The problem: IE & Firefox - work but do not load the styles of the child pages nor execute their document.ready functions
Chrome - 404 error

The jQuery behind it all:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.child').hide();
    $('.parent').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.child', $(this).parent()).slideToggle('slow');
    });

    $('a').click(function(event) {
        var innerText = $(this).attr('href');
        var elem = $('#' + innerText);
        if(elem.length > 0) {
            $('#container').load("Pages/" + elem[0].innerHTML + ".html", function(response, status, xhr) {
                if (status == "error") {
                    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                    $("#container").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + " <b>"+elem[0].innerHTML+"</b>");
                }
            });
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Chrome header:

> Request URL:file:///D:/PacientData/Pages/labDemandeCode1.html
>   OPTIONS file:///D:/PacientData/Pages/labDemandeCode1.html HTTP/1.1
>   Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
>   Origin: null
>   Access-Control-Request-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Accept

Any help regarding both problems would be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `file://` when you're testing AJAX stuff. It will not work very well. Put your files on a webserver, even if it is a local IIS of Apache server.

Comment: not an option due to the fact that this web site should work on a filesystem not a web server. The purpose will be to be posted on a memory stick and delivered to the client and he/she should be able to just plug the stick in and open the website.

Comment: Well, you got a problem then. It will keep giving you problems. Either don't use AJAX, or add a small program that acts like a web server.

Comment: There must be a way given that it works on IE and on Firefox but it doesn't work on Chrome

Comment: That it works on some versions is no guarantee it should work on every browser. It is blocked in Chrome because of security issues and it's unclear if they're going to fix it: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787

Comment: Thanks for that. I will have to issue a don't use Chrome on the release. I'm sorry to do that but, it seems i have no choice. maybe i'll make a workaround something similar to links and new pages for chrome.

Comment: I don't know what your target platform is, but like I said, you could add a stand-alone webserver application. It doesn't need to be big and it can listen to some obscure port (say 12345). Then, instead of opening a certain page, the user can startup some script or program that configures and starts that webserver and opens `localhost:12345/index.htm`. Apache is very light, but still to heavy for this purpose, but there are quite a couple of even lighter ones that would do for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

**If your url is good** (look in firebug..) it may be **the header of the server's response** header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); can fix this 404 sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't test your code through `file:` URLS but via HTTP, e.g. by installing a webserver locally. Especially with AJAX there are quite some problems when working in a `file:` environment.